# Converting a jquery element to html changes input values to name of input

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am stumped. I have a div with several elements inside of it. Some of those elements are inputs. I need to make is so the user can edit the elements inside of the div. The problem is the value of those inputs are not displayed, instead they are stored in a database. I need to retrieve those values and attach them to the inputs and then display that to the user to edit. The problem is that once the new values are attached (which works fine) when I try to convert those elements back into html to put inside my editor the value is replaced with the name if the input is a checkbox and the value disappears if the input is text. I have the following code

```
var text = $('#parentDiv').html();              //this is the div with several elements inside 
var elements = $(text);                    //convert each of those children into jquery elements
var found = $('input', elements);              //get all inputs
found.each(function(){                         //for each input element
var input = $(this);
var name = input.attr('name');             //get the name of that element
$.post('getinputvalue.php', {id: id, name: name})    //get the saved value of that element from my database
    .done(function(data){
        input.attr('value', data);    //set the value of that input equal to the value retrieved from the database
        $('input[name="'+name+'"]', elements).replaceWith(input);  // replace the original input with the new input element which has the correct value

    });

});
console.log(elements);                          //this shows each element and the inputs have the correct value
var blankDiv = $("<div />").append(elements);  // attach the elements to a div so I can get the new html to input back into a text editor
    console.log(blankDiv.html());                    //the input elements now have the name of the input copied into the value attribute for checkboxes and the value is gone for text inputs instead of the correct value
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

the getinputvalue code is here:

```
<?php session_start();
require_once('../functions/questionfunctions.php');
require_once('../functions/globalfunctions.php');
require_once('../includes/connect.php');

$id = htmlspecialchars($_POST['id']);
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$cans = getSpecificFormCans($id, $name)->fetchColumn();
echo $cans;
```

Comment: php side code would be helpful

Comment: What's an example of the console output for `console.log(elements);`?

Comment: Here is the innerHTML property for one of the inputs from the console.log       ` innerHTML: "This is checked&nbsp;<input name="box1" type="checkbox" value="1">" `    Then the output of blankDiv.html() is ` <input name="box1" type="checkbox" value="box1">`

Comment: I thought the name was copied into value, but `box1` != `1`? Also, where is `id` coming from?

Comment: All those `$.post`'s happen asynchronously - have you tried `console.log(elements)` _after_ all the `$.post`'s are done?

Comment: Sorry, id is coming from #parentDiv, all these elements are a part of a quiz question. The id is the unique id for the question each element is associated with.

Comment: The elements variable has the correct values, it is only after it gets converted to html that the input values change

Comment: In case you are getting some unexpected behavior, i'll recommend: 
using: 
var found = $('#parentDiv > input');  to get all the inputs.

Comment: Christoffer you're genius! Thank you so much. Switching the post to ajax and forcing async to false soved the problem. For some reason I thought that since the ajax calls were inside an each loop the events after the each loop would be executed after the post calls were complete. Thank you for saving me another 2 hours!